# capture mouse click in php

Tags: php, click, mouse, capture

I am developing a website where I have come across a problem. The thing is, the user has to select one image out of the 3 images that I am displaying. 
How to capture that click and store that particular clicked image in the database? 
My sql is the dB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? It seems pretty simple - capture it with JS and send an Ajax request to store it server-side.

Comment: You cannot capture a mouse click in php, as php runs serverside, not client side, php doesn't know what a mouse is. You'd need to provide some more details on what you've already done/want doing if you'd want this to be done without the use of JS.

Comment: What you need is java script not PHP see `http://api.jquery.com/click/` and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I understood. I will try now using JS and Ajax. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

PHP (typically) has nothing to do with graphical user interfaces. The user interface you are probably talking about is HTML in the browser. The HTML way of doing this is a checkbox/radio button in a form with a submit button. Possibly the images can be the submit button instead. For something more dynamic, you need to use Javascript.

Comment: +1, well said. AJAX is almost a definite in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case seems to be having a record of the image clicked by user.

1. If the images are 3 separate images, then `img` tags may record the clicked image, either as part of a form (server-side) or javascript (client side)
2. If the 3 images are part of one larger image, then **image maps** may be what you're after:

> `ismap` attribute indicates a [server-side image map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_ismap.asp); when clicked, the coordinates are sent to the server as a URL query string.
> The `usemap` attribute specifies an image as a client-side image map (an image map is an image with clickable areas).